# Using Scrapy to scrape a webpage

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape the largest table from this page. I am working in conda prompt

http://www.tennisabstract.com/cgi-bin/player-classic.cgi?p=RafaelNadal&f=ACareerqq

Here is my attempt:

```
scrapy shell
fetch('http://www.tennisabstract.com/cgi-bin/player-classic.cgi?p=RafaelNadal&f=ACareerqq')
table = response.xpath('//table[@id="matches"]')
rows = table.xpath('//tr')
```

This seems to grab the correct table, but the rows I'm getting are not correct; they are coming from the top of the webpage.

My other try was this:

```
table = response.xpath('//table[@id="matches"]//tr')
```

But this just returns an empty list.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 0):

`table.extract()` is returning empty table `['<table id="matches"></table>']` here. 
It seem data getting loaded dynamically in the table.
You would require to use Selenium or ScrapyJS to get data in such cases.
[See the link for more info](http://%60table.extract()%60%20is%20returning%20empty%20table%20%60['%3Ctable%20id=%22matches%22%3E%3C/table%3E']%60%20here.%20It%20seem%20data%20getting%20loaded%20latter%20using%20some%20ajax%20call.%20you%20may%20require%20Selenium%20or%20ScrapyJS%20to%20get%20data)